# P-touch editor for Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: printing, brother, editor

I'm the owner of a Brother QL-500 that worked great when I used Windows 8.1, all the drivers, and the program P-touch editor was there.

I have tried to get it to work on Ubuntu: http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadtop.aspx?c=dk&lang=da&prod=lpql550euk_same

I have tried Linux with .deb and .rpm but none of them seems to work. I'm thinking it's just the driver for the printer itself, and not the program P-touch editor.

Can someone please help me to get a solution for this problem, it's the last thing I need so I can say: "Ubuntu is perfect!" :-) If there is another program instead of P-touch editor that would still work with the Brother QL-500 that it would also be great.

I have installed this source to get .rpm working..

```
sudo apt-get install alien dpkg-dev debhelper build-essential

sudo alien packagename.rpm

sudo dpkg -i packagename.deb
```

But the files I download from Brother's website, does not give me a .rpm I can convert to .deb.

Comment: I googled "Brother QL-500 linux"
found this: http://support.brother.com/g/b/oslist.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=lpql500eus
just click "linux information" it looks well documented